# Bug on Reply to @reply.careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I answered to questions:

[image]

But seems like recipient got only:

[image]

Comment: So what did you expect? What went wrong?

Comment: In email I wrote answers to all questions, as you can see on screenshot, but in stackowerflow "messages" panel - i see my answer containing only "Hello!" (seems like it cuts from place where quotes begin, but it thrown away my answers)

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the notification, you have to reply *above* the line. Anything below it will be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

The message says `-- Reply above this line --`. It seems you answered some questions above it... and the rest below it.

Only the message part above the *reply* line is actually sent. The rest is cut off.